# Jenkinsfile pipeline option: when equivalent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am searching a way to define pipeline `options` based on JOB_NAME in declarative pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    options {
        when { expression { return env.JOB_NAME.equals('test_job') } }       <----------
                    
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
```

and I am getting the error

```
11:23:15  WorkflowScript: 39: Options definitions cannot have blocks @ line 39, column 9.
11:23:15             when { expression { return env.JOB_NAME.equals('test_job') } }
```

Any workaround to achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: The option _Execute concurrent builds if necessary_ isn't activated in jobs' GUI configs by default. Do you really need to deactivate it explicitely in a pipeline script?  (And you cannot de-/activate options conditionally in the GUI, either.)

Comment: Let's assume you got what you want, build A of the job runs and decides that concurrent builds should be enabled. Concurrently, build B of the job runs and decides that concurrent jobs should be disabled. What should happen to build A and build B?